# In R, convert daily to yearly

Tags: r, group-by

In R, is there a way to use "group_by" and convert daily data to yearly data using last() of all variable in one go rather than using summarise of each variable?

Comment: It would be better with a reproducible data set and an expected output. You can take a look at lubridate::floor_date() though.

Comment: Hey, thanks. See the issue is, in my data there are 50 variables, hence writing "summarise" inside "group_by" one by one is time taking. Rather than using that, can you suggest any other way?

Comment: What about `group_by(year(date)) %>% slice(n())`? That way you get the last row of each year. I am assuming that your first column is `date` and that it is ordered. Otherwise you should do `arrange(date)` before grouping to make sure the last row of the group is the last day of the year.

Comment: Without sample data and expected output, this seems likely to miss the mark.

Comment: With many variables, `across()` is your friend.  But, as been said at least twice before, you can help yourself by helping us to help you by providing a minimal reproducible example.  This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will help.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. it worked. Another method to use is "summerise_all"

Answer (score 0):

```
(adf <- data.frame(
  year=rep(1:3,each=3),
  month=rep(1:3,times=3),
  var1= letters[1:9],
  var2= -9:-1
))

#solution
library(tidyverse)
group_by(adf,
         year) |>
  summarise(across(.cols = everything(),
                   .fns = last))
```

Comment: Your answer could benefit from some explanation.